# Connect to SQL Server 2016 with always encrypted feature

Tags: sql-server-2016, rhel7, always-encrypted

I am trying to use always encrypted column with SQL Server 2016 and RHEL 7.

I have created my DSN `in /etc/odbc.ini`.

Info reg `odbc.ini` is

```
[test]
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.8.0
Description=My Sample ODBC Database Connection
Trace=Yes
Server=ip address of sqlserver 2016
Database=Test
ColumnEncryption=Enabled
```

I have tried to put the column master key in .crt format in

```
/ssl/private and /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/.
```

I am using the command to connect

```
sqlcmd  -D -S test -U test -P test -d Test -Q "select * from empInfo"
```

I am getting the error

> Sqlcmd: Error: Internal error at ReadAndHandleColumnData (Reason: Error reading column data).
>   SqlState CE200, Keystore provider MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE not found. Ensure that the appropriate Keystore provider library has been loaded.

Can anyone help me with this? It seems like that it is not picking up the certificate. If that is the case then what will be the location of the crt file to put?

Regards,
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

Currently,  MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE is not supported on Linux. You will have to use Azure Key Vault. Please refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver)